# How to optimize Exporting CSV in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to export the mean LST values over a region for MODIS and Landsat datasets. I understand that using reducer.mean() requires high computational resources, but I have already masked out all the cloudy pixels and I am not sure why it's taking so long. There are only around 3000 images in my MODIS collection, and performing the operation on a smaller ROI still takes a long time to process. My code is a bit extensive and posting all of it here would make the post too long, so here is the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/561d0457c18c3e02cced24cce3bf24f1) for the code. How can I streamline the process so that I can speed up the exporting?
An outline for the code is given below:

1. Used the QA mask on Terra Day and Aqua Night,
2. Upscaled the collection using bilinear interpolation,
3. Created a mean LST image collection for modis
4. Masked out cloudy pixels from Landsat 8 using QA-Pixel,
5. Mosaiced the landsat images and created a new image collection with the mosaiced images,
6. Joined the modis and landsat image collections based on acquisition date,
7. Created an algorithm that filters only overlaping pixels from the modis mean lst image by creating a mask from the corresponding landsat image,
8. Used reducer.mean() over the the final images and exported both in a single csv.
9. Loaded in points representing 11 weather stations, created 50km buffers around them and repeated the process of importing the reduced LST for the region of the buffer. (This is also taking very long to export)

Currently, the export has been going on in excess of 8 hours, and the only one of the buffer exports was successful which took 11 hours to export.

Note: I found that without bit-masking the landsat images I cannot get a consistent result ( I get huge outliers such as temperatures like -120 and 50 C) therefore I cannot omit that process from the script. Part of my code is given below (Without the point data added)

```
var landSurfaceTemperatureVis = {
 min: 13000.0,
 max: 16500.0,
 palette: [
   '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
   '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
   '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
   'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
   'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
 ],
};

var terraD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
 .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2023-01-01').select(['LST_Day_1km','QC_Day'])
 .filterBounds(geometry)
 

var terraN = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
 .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2023-01-01')
 .select(['LST_Night_1km', 'QC_Night'])
 .filterBounds(geometry);
 
var filterD = function(image){ 
 var qa = image.select('QC_Day');
 var mask = qa.eq(0);
 return image.select('LST_Day_1km').updateMask(mask).clip(geometry);
};
var filterN = function(image){ 
 var qa = image.select('QC_Night');
 var bitMask2 = 1 << 2;
 var bitMask3 = 1 << 3;
 var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(bitMask2).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(bitMask3).eq(0));
 return image.select('LST_Night_1km').updateMask(mask);
};

var terraD = terraD.map(filterD)
var terraN = terraN.map(filterN)

function maskClouds(image) {
 var pixelQA = image.select('QA_PIXEL').uint16(); // Explicitly cast to uint16
 var cloudMask = pixelQA.bitwiseAnd(ee.Number(1).leftShift(3)).eq(0) // Cloud shadow
                .and(pixelQA.bitwiseAnd(ee.Number(1).leftShift(4)).eq(0)); // Cloud
 return image.updateMask(cloudMask);
}

var landsatD = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
 .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2023-01-01')
 .select(['ST_B10', 'QA_PIXEL'])
 .filterBounds(geometry)
 .map(function (img){
   return img.multiply(0.00341802).add(149).subtract(273.15)
             .set("system:time_start", ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).update({hour:0, minute:0, second:0}).millis());
 });

landsatD = landsatD.map(maskClouds)

// Function to clip each image in the ImageCollection to the ROI
var clipToROI = function(image) {
 return image.clip(geometry);
};

var clipTerraD = terraD.map(clipToROI);
Map.addLayer(clipTerraD.limit(5), landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'TerraD');

var clipTerraN = terraN.map(clipToROI);
//Map.addLayer(clipTerraN, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'AquaD');

var clipLandsat = landsatD.map(clipToROI);
//Map.addLayer(clipLandsat);

//////////UPSCALE////////////////////

// Function to upscale an image using bilinear interpolation
var upscaleBilinear = function(image) {
 return image.resample('bilinear').reproject({
   crs: image.projection(),
   scale: 100  // Set the desired scale (resolution)
 });
};

// Apply bilinear interpolation to the Terra and Aqua datasets
var bilinearTerraD = clipTerraD.map(upscaleBilinear);
var bilinearTerraN = clipTerraN.map(upscaleBilinear);
// Add the upscaled Terra and Aqua layers to the map with the specified visualization
//Map.addLayer(bilinearTerraD, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'MODIS Terra (Upscaled)');
//Map.addLayer(bilinearTerraN, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'MODIS Aqua (Upscaled)');

// Join Terra and Aqua images based on acquisition date
var join = ee.Join.inner().apply({
 primary: bilinearTerraD,
 secondary: bilinearTerraN,
 condition: ee.Filter.equals({
   leftField: 'system:time_start',
   rightField: 'system:time_start'
 })
});

var calculateMean = function(image) {
 // Get the Terra and Aqua images
 var terraDImage = ee.Image(image.get('primary')).select('LST_Day_1km');
 var terraNImage = ee.Image(image.get('secondary')).select('LST_Night_1km');
 
 // Calculate the mean of Terra and Aqua images
 var meanImage = terraDImage.add(terraNImage)
   .divide(2)
   .multiply(0.02)
   .subtract(273.15)
   .rename('mean_LST');
 
 // Return the mean image with the acquisition date
 return meanImage.set('system:time_start', ee.Date(terraDImage.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
};


// Apply the calculateMean function to the joined ImageCollection
var meanCollection = ee.ImageCollection(join.map(calculateMean));
print('meancollection', meanCollection)

print('meanCollection size' ,meanCollection.size())

print('Landsat Image Collection size',clipLandsat.size());


var start = ee.Date('2013-01-01');
var finish = ee.Date('2023-01-01');

// Difference in days between start and finish
var diff = finish.difference(start, 'day')

// Make a list of all dates
var range = ee.List.sequence(0, diff.subtract(1)).map(function(day){return start.advance(day,'day')})

// Funtion for iteraton over the range of dates
var day_mosaics = function(date, newlist) {
 // Cast
 date = ee.Date(date)
 newlist = ee.List(newlist)

 // Filter collection between date and the next day
 var filtered = clipLandsat.filterDate(date, date.advance(1,'day'))

 // Make the mosaic
 var image = ee.Image(filtered.mosaic())
 
  // Set the date as a property on the image
 image = image.set('system:time_start', date.format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
 
 // Add the mosaic to a list only if the collection has images
 return ee.List(ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size(), newlist.add(image), newlist))
 ;
}

// Iterate over the range to make a new list, and then cast the list to an imagecollection
var newcol = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(range.iterate(day_mosaics, ee.List([]))))
print(newcol)

var meanLandsatJoin = ee.Join.inner().apply({
 primary: meanCollection,
 secondary: newcol,
 condition: ee.Filter.equals({
   leftField: 'system:time_start',
   rightField: 'system:time_start'
 })
});
print('combined_collection', meanLandsatJoin)

var maskMODISWithLandsat = function(modisImage, landsatImage) {
 // Create a mask from the non-null pixels of the ST_B10 band in the Landsat image
 var mask = landsatImage.select('ST_B10').mask();

 // Apply the mask to the MODIS image
 var maskedModisImage = modisImage.updateMask(mask);

 // Return the masked MODIS image
 return maskedModisImage;
};

var combinedMaskedCollection = meanLandsatJoin.map(function(pair) {
 var modisImage = ee.Image(pair.get('primary')).select('mean_LST');
 var landsatImage = ee.Image(pair.get('secondary')).select('ST_B10');

 return maskMODISWithLandsat(modisImage, landsatImage);
});

// Example of adding the first image of the masked collection to the map
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(combinedMaskedCollection.first()), landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'Masked MODIS Image');

var combineAndReduce = function(pair) {
 var modisImage = ee.Image(pair.get('primary')).select('mean_LST');
 var landsatImage = ee.Image(pair.get('secondary')).select('ST_B10');
 
 // Mask MODIS image
 var mask = landsatImage.mask();
 var maskedModisImage = modisImage.updateMask(mask);
 
 // Reduce both images to mean values over the geometry
 var meanModisLST = maskedModisImage.reduceRegion({
   reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
   geometry: geometry,
   scale: 100, // Adjust as needed
   maxPixels: 1e9
 }).get('mean_LST');
 
 var meanST_B10 = landsatImage.reduceRegion({
   reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
   geometry: geometry,
   scale: 100, // Adjust as needed
   maxPixels: 1e9
 }).get('ST_B10');

 // Get the date from the MODIS image
 var date = ee.Date(modisImage.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
 
 return ee.Feature(null, {
   'mean_LST': meanModisLST,
   'ST_B10': meanST_B10,
   'date': date
 });
};

var combinedAndReduced = meanLandsatJoin.map(combineAndReduce);
Export.table.toDrive({
 collection: combinedAndReduced,
 description: 'Masked_MODIS_LST_and_Landsat_ST_B10',
 fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```